# Accessing webcam with PHP?

Tags: php, webcam

Is it technically possible using PHP? For example allow visitors of my website to  view their own webcam, taking a shot, and upload the file onto a directory, also onto my MySQL-DB.

Comment: Simple answer is NO. Accessing webcam means controlling hardware and since PHP runs on server side and outputs html+css+jvascript so it is not directly possible to access webcam using php. May be you could improve your question.

Comment: This post may be helpful to you http://www.vivekmoyal.in/webcam-in-php-how-to-use-webcam-in-php/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, PHP is a server-side language and thus cannot access client hardware.

However, modern browsers give JavaScript code access to webcam, microphone, etc. so you could record something and then submit it to the server. [Photobooth.js](http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/) might be worth a look.

Of course you *could* use Flash, Silverlight or a Java Applet for it, too. But only the former is available on almost every PC. Besides that, you should avoid Flash when you don't absolutely need it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

PHP is run in your server, and it has no knowledge of the user's machine or hardware and even if it had it, you can't use them.

You have to use some client-side programming, using javascript, HTML5 or Flash and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Simply No

Server side language cannot control client side hardware....

You need something that can work on client side like flash,javascript etc

However I found this http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ jquery plugin..
You can have look at

Answer (score 1):

No. As @ThiefMaster said, is a server technology. If you want to access client webcam you can use:

- FLASH
- Silverlight
- JavaScript/HTML5 (with `getUserMedia()`)

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) is an introduction for how to do that in HTML5. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is NO. You can use javascript , jQuery or flash to access webcam 
http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
http://www.scriptcam.com/docs.cfm